# How to utilize external form and retrieve POST data from external form using SuiteScript?

Tags: iframe, suitescript2.0

If there is an external form that posts some secure user data, and then one wanted to get that POST data from the form to flow into NetSuite, is there a way to accomplish this in SuiteScript? A simple example of how the form will be displayed, utilizing an iframe:

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'],
    function(serverWidget) {
        function onRequest(context) {
        var func = 'test';
        var request = context.request;
        var url = 'https://www.sample.com/sample-form.html'; // Not a real form
        var title = 'TEST';

        if(request.method == 'GET') {
            try {
                var content = '<iframe width=960px height=100% style="height:640px;" src=' + url + '></iframe>'

                var newForm = serverWidget.createForm({
                    title: title
                });

                var newField = newForm.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_form',
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
                    label: 'TEST'
                });

                newField.defaultValue = content;
                context.response.writePage(newForm);
            }
            catch(e){
                log.error(func, JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        }
        else {
        }
    }

    return {
      onRequest: onRequest
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.postMessage` to pass data from external form and add client script on the suitelet to listen to data using `window.addEventListener`.

To attach client script on a form you can use the following

```
newForm.clientScriptModulePath = './FILE_PATH_TO_CLIENT_SCRIPT';
```

where `newForm` is `form` object returned from `serverWidget.createForm` and in client script you can have *pageInit* which would initialize the **eventListener**.